# Cache Expiration On Static Images

Tags: php, caching

I have a php site using html5 run on a linux server on godaddy.   I need to set a cache expiration date on static images and a css file.  I also need to gzip a css file and cannot seem to find the correct syntax for either.   I am not sure if I am making this too complicated or what.  Am I correct to think I can get this done with an expire header in the top of my php pages?   I feel lost and I know what i am doing! I do not have control over the server.

Comment: Do you have access to your apache/php configuration file? can you use .htaccess files to control your apache settings?

Comment: I have access to my php config file.  YES, I can use htaccess to control apache settings.  However htaccess is in my wordpress dir not my root.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely possible if you have control over the server, and maybe possible through .htaccess if you're on shared hosting.

Try these SO questions:

- [How to gzip my files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294976/how-do-i-gzip-my-web-files)
- [How to set the cache expiry period of a whole folder of jpgs using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788833/how-to-set-the-cache-expiry-period-of-a-whole-folder-of-jpgs-using-htaccess)
- [Why isn’t my javascript & css caching ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841209) (With full examples)

Answer (score 2):

Godaddy can be extremely frustrating. I have been seeking a means of using expires header with Godaddy hosting for some time and haven't found a solution yet.

I have the following in htaccess ('A2592000' indicates 1 month) and it works with other hosts but not Godaddy :(

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
```

Answer (score 1):

I had completely same problem. Disaster with GoDaddy. Never more their hosting :(

But I found solution:
https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6908/enabling-mod_expires-with-your-hosting-account?locale=en

I do not know how you manage your hosting but I use FileZila to connect to FTP. So after I connect to FTP you can rewrite .htaccess file :) so download original one and add this code after:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Activate mod_expires for this directory
ExpiresActive on

# locally cache common image types for 7 days
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"

# cache CSS files for 24 hours
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 24 hours"
```

I hope this will help you. (it helped me:D)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)$">
ExpiresDefault A0
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0,  no-cache, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

Which mean, that expiration date is in access moment and set headers to 0 values.

As You can see, here You can add more filetypes

/via http://blog.simplemediacode.com/cache-expiration-on-static-images-and-content-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400"
```

Where max-age is set in seconds.

Additional, if your contents is still not being cached, read my post at [Why isn't my javascript & css caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841209/why-isnt-my-javascript-css-caching/8497239#8497239) for additional cache-config-magic.